# R - how to reference values in a table() nested in a list?

Tags: r

I'm generating a series of tables with the command `table()` that I'm storing together in a list, and I want to reference specific values of each table to use in calculation. I can correctly pull out the correct table from my list but I can't seem to find the correct way to reference the values within the table.

Here is my table (I don't think it matters, but I'm referencing this table within my list with code `tables$'10'[1]`):

```
[[1]]
          label.test
test_pred  Disorder Normal
  Disorder        7      4
  Normal          8     16
```

I'd like to be able to pull out one of those numbers, for example the 4 which seems like it would be referred to with [1,2]. I've tried nesting more brackets inside like this `[1[1,2]]`, or chaining the square brackets one after another like this `[1][1,2]`, or using more of the `$` notation, but none of these have worked so far.

How can I reference the values in the table?

Comment: the first element of the list is referenced with double brackets. doesn't `tables[[1]][1,2]` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it just gave me an error that I had the wrong dimension, so I'd add another `[1]` and try again. I actually reached a point where I had `tables[[1]][1][1][1]` and it was still showing me the same table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have a nested list which may need more attention. Without seeing your code, I guess you can try

```
 tables$'10'[1][[1]][1,2]
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a nested list but this does the trick! Huh, I kept trying this with only the first `1` in double brackets and when it didn't produce any change I stopped using it, but it looks like it needed to be the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

This should be clear enough:

```
b <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10))
table(b)
c <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10))
table(b)

tables <- list(table(b),table(c))

> tables
[[1]]
b
 A  B  C 
10 10 10 

[[2]]
c
 A  B  C 
10 10 10
```

To access the first , second or third element of the first table:

```
> tables[[1]][1]
 A 
10 
> tables[[1]][2]
 B 
10 
> tables[[1]][3]
 C 
10
```

It is the the same thing for the second table or any table. You need double square brackets `[[]]` at the beginning to access the element of the list